# ggplot2: add line and points showing means (stat_summary)

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I am using this data frame:

```
xym <- data.frame(
  Var1 = c("vloga", "odločitve", "dolgoročno", 
         "krizno", "uživa v", "vloga",   "odločitve", 
         "dolgoročno",  "krizno",   "uživa v", "vloga",
         "odločitve","dolgoročno", "krizno",   "uživa v",
         "vloga","odločitve",  "dolgoročno", "krizno",
         "uživa v"),
  Var2 = c("Nad","Nad", "Nad",  "Nad",  "Nad", "Pod",
         "Pod",  "Pod",  "Pod",  "Pod",  "Enak","Enak",
         "Enak", "Enak", "Enak", "Sam.", "Sam.", "Sam.",
         "Sam.", "Sam."),
  value = c(4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.5,
             2, 3.5 ,5 ,6 ,6 ,5 ,6))
```

And with this code:

```
p <- ggplot(xym, aes(x = Var1, y = value, fill = Var2)) + coord_flip()+
  theme_bw() + scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow", "deepskyblue1", "yellowgreen","orchid4")) + xlim(rev(levels(xym$Var1)))+ theme(axis.title=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),legend.position = "bottom",
                                                                                                                                     axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0,vjust = 0.4)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.7, position = position_dodge(width=0.7)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = Var1, y =max(value), label = round(value, 2), fill = Var2), 
            angle = 0, position = position_dodge(width = 0.7), size = 4.2)
p + labs(fill="")

p +  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="line", aes(group = 1))
```

I produce output:

[image]

But beside the **red line** which is marking total average by question (i.e. "dolgoročno", "krizno" etc.) I would like to **add points** and next to the bars as well as **labels** of the individual question group mean

My output should look something like the picture below, (I did it in paint), where the black dots represent my desired points and the value 3.6 of the  first dot is the average of (6,2,4,2.5) and represents my desired value labels.

[image]

I've also looked at:

[Plot average line in a facet_wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650091/plot-average-line-in-a-facet-wrap)

[ggplot2: line connecting the means of grouped data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621963/ggplot2-line-connecting-the-means-of-grouped-data)

[How to label graph with the mean of the values using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242174/how-to-label-graph-with-the-mean-of-the-values-using-ggplot2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option would be the following. I followed your code and added a few lines.

```
# Your code
p <- ggplot(xym, aes(x = Var1, y = value, fill = Var2)) +
     coord_flip() +
     theme_bw() +
     scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow", "deepskyblue1", "yellowgreen","orchid4")) +
     xlim(rev(levels(xym$Var1))) +
     theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
           axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
           legend.position = "bottom",
           axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0,vjust = 0.4)) +
     geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.7, position = position_dodge(width = 0.7)) +
     geom_text(aes(x = Var1, y = max(value), label = round(value, 2), fill = Var2), 
               angle = 0, position = position_dodge(width = 0.7), size = 4.2)

p + labs(fill = "")
```

Then, I added the following code. You can add dots changing geom to `point` in stat_summary. For labels, I chose to get data from `ggplot_build()` and crated a data frame called `foo`. (I think there are other ways to do the same job.) Using `foo`, I added annotation in the end.

```
p2 <- p +
      stat_summary(fun.y = mean, color = "red", geom = "line", aes(group = 1)) + 
      stat_summary(fun.y = mean, color = "black", geom ="point", aes(group = 1), size = 5,
                   show.legend = FALSE)

# This is the data for your dots in the graph
foo <- as.data.frame(ggplot_build(p2)$data[[4]])

p2 +
annotate("text", x = foo$x, y = foo$y + 0.5, color = "black", label = foo$y)
```

[image]